# How can i access a MediaPlayer created in a Service from an Activity/Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Suppose i have created a `MediaPlayer` in my Service class...

```
public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

How would i be able to access this instance from an Activity or Fragment?

For example, if the `MediaPlayer` was created in an Activity i would be able to access the instance in a Fragment like this...

**MainActivity**

Initialising MediaPlayer....

```
public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

**Fragment**

Accessing MediaPlayer from Fragment...

```
private MediaPlayer mp = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mp;
```

**Question:** Can i access a MediaPlayer instance created in a `Service` class from a `Fragment`, in the same way as shown above?

Comment: You can directly access by class name that is MainActivity because you have declared public static MediaPlayer instance.

Comment: So how would i access the MediaPlayer, if it was created in a Service?

Comment: You have declare in service like public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); Now You can access ServiceClassName.mp. You can declare mediaPlayer  in activity in whcih you have started service. It is better then service.

Comment: Oh, and how would i declare it from a fragment?

Comment: use Bound Service

Answer (score 1):

You should check Bound Service documentation. The idea of this class that you are able to bind service to specific activity/fragment. Interaction between UI and service can be don't for example using Messenger class.